# Use of 싫다/좋다 as affirmation/negation

Tags: vocabulary, verb

In [(G)I-DLE's *Put It Straight*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIAtuJ31l98), lyrics include the following lines:

> **싫다고 말해** / 사랑하지 않는다고 말해 봐 / 내 맘이 떠날 거 같이 / 너가 미워질 거 같이
>
> **좋다고 말해** / 아니 사랑하고 있다고 말해 줘 /  좋았던 그때와 같이 / 이제 사랑할 순 없니

I read 싫다고 말해 and 좋다고 말해 translated in some sites as "say no" and "say yes" respectively. However, I was understanding them as "say you don't like it" and "say you like it/it's fine" because of a naïve translation. What am I missing? Are there actual cases where 싫다 and 좋다 refer to affirmation or negation or is it rather a special case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that lyrics, your translation is correct. But there are some cases where you can say 싫다/싫어 to mean 아니: when someone suggests you to do something, you can say "싫어/싫다/싫습니다/..." to mean 아니. It works like "(I) don't like (your idea/suggestion)". You can also say 좋아/좋다/좋습니다 to mean yes, but while 싫어 is a very common response, 좋아 is less common. A more natural positive response (in my opinion) is 그래/그러자/그럽시다. For negative response, one can also say 안 해/안 한다/안 할 거다/안 합니다/안 할 겁니다, which means "(I) don't/won't do (it)".